# Returning unpacked list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function in python that takes any number of arguments, runs some operations on the arguments and lastly returns the new values. Eg:

```
def foo(*args):
    return *[i ** 2 for i in args] # error: cant use starred expression here

a, b, c, d = foo(2, 15, 17, 21)
```

instead of "unpacking" the list it just spits out a syntax error. I could technically leave out the "unpacking" all together and just have the user write

```
def foo(*args):
    return [i ** 2 for i in args]

a, b, c, d = foo(2, 15, 17, 21) # works

e = foo(82) # e is now a list and not just the value
```

this works when having multiple arguments but not when I only give one. Is there any way to do this easily without the need of using an if-statement to check the number of inputs given?

Comment: Iterables can be unpacked including `list`. You can just return a list. But still it is very danger since its length is not checked.

Comment: “Unpacked values” aren’t a thing. You can return something that can be unpacked and then unpack it. One item would be a special case you’d either need to handle on the caller side, or within the function by returning not-a-list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack a one value list, you just need a comma after the one name you're assigning to:

```
e, = foo(82)
```

This is the same kind of syntax you need to use when creating a 1-tuple. You need to use `(x,)`, because `(x)` is identical to `x` (the parentheses don't create the tuple, the comma does).

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(*args):
    return [i ** 2 for i in args]

a, b, c, d = foo(2, 15, 17, 21)
```

works as intended. Of course, you must ensure that the returned list has exactly as many items as you have on the left side of the assignment.

Comment: Oh sorry I should have been clearer. That works when the number of arguments are higher than one. If you only input one argument you get a list as the result.